# How to create sub-DatafFrame with minimal values count

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pandas-groupby

I have a `DataFrame` of the form:

```
    a   b Class
0   1  10     A
1   2  12     A
2   3   2     A
3  12   5     B
4   5   7     A
5   6   8     B
6   7  17     A
7   1   1     B
8   5   0     B
```

From this `DataFrame` I want to get a another `DataFrame` that has at least N rows for each of the values of column `Class`  (here at least N rows from class 'A' and N rows of class B).

The new `DataFrame` should include all the rows starting from the end of the `DataFrame` and down to the row where the condition is met.

In the data above with N=2 I expect to get:

```
   a   b Class
4  5   7     A
5  6   8     B
6  7  17     A
7  1   1     B
8  5   0     B
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why tehere are 3 times `B` ? Not need `df.groupby('Class').tail(2)` ?

Comment: I want all the rows starting from the end of the dataframe until all classes have at least N rows

Comment: But why there are 3 times `B` ?

Comment: Because only in index 4 I'll have at least 2 'A' rows counting from the end of the dataframe. So the index for me to slice is 4

Comment: @jezrael I've edited the question so it will be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the last 2 items by Class and the first index of the result.

Then index from this point onwards on your original dataframe.

```
idx = df.groupby('Class').tail(2).index[0]

res = df[idx:]

print(res)

   a   b Class
4  5   7     A
5  6   8     B
6  7  17     A
7  1   1     B
8  5   0     B
```

Comment: Great. It is simpler than i thought. Thanks